# Parallel processing in Scala 2.9

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, parallel-collections

Suppose I have an array of ~10K elements and I need to process all elements of the array. I would like to process them in such a way that only `K` elements are processed in parallel.

I use `Scala 2.9`. I tried parallel collections (see below) but I saw *more* than `K` elements processed in parallel.

```
import collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks.defaultForkJoinPool._
val old = getParallelism
setParallelism(K)
val result = myArray.par.map(...) // process the array in parallel
setParallelism(old)
```

How would you suggest process an array in `Scala 2.9` in such a way that only `K` elements are processed in parallel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setParallelism` method sets the recommended number of parallel workers that fork/join pool of the parallel collection is supposed to use. Those `K` workers may work on any part of the collection - it is up to the scheduler to decide which elements the workers will be assigned to.

If you would like to include only first `K` elements in the parallel operation, you should use the `take` method, followed by a `map`:

```
myArray.par.take(K).map(...)
```

You can alternatively use `view.take(K).map(...).force` to create a parallel view before doing the mapping.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate a bit on using `view` ?

Comment: The idea behind views is to postpone evaluating the intermediate collections that would otherwise be created in memory using `take`, `map` or `filter` until the collection is `force`d. Due to certain abstraction penalties and indirections, this may or may not increase performance, depending on what the transformations are. You can read more about it here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/views.html